# Need to filter the Spark dataframe with filter values from iterating over multiple columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataset in Spark dataframe. I need to filter based on given conditions:

- equals to: `ID: (6, 7, 8, 9, 13, 15, 16, 18)`
- NOT equals to: `STATE :(Illinois, Oklahoma)`, `CITY: (Orange, Boca_Raton)`

I need to iterate over these columns to get the filter values as key-value pair instead of hardcoding the values and filter the dataframe to get the result df.

| id | NAME | CITY | STATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Roseann | Richmond | Virginia |
| 3 | Jameson | Fort_Lauderdale | Florida |
| 4 | Marline | Washington | District_of_Columbia |
| 5 | Ivory | Macon | Georgia |
| 6 | Toby | San_Diego | California |
| 7 | Isacco | Honolulu | Illinois |
| 8 | Sallee | Orange | California |
| 9 | Lannie | Peoria | Oklahoma |
| 10 | Bradley | Tulsa | Oklahoma |
| 11 | Teodora | Pittsburgh | Pennsylvania |
| 12 | Benedikta | Tampa | Florida |
| 13 | Zelma | Newport_News | California |
| 14 | Carilyn | Flint | Michigan |
| 15 | Joey | Boca_Raton | California |
| 16 | Pattie | Boston | Massachusetts |
| 17 | Dag | Bismarck | North_Dakota |
| 18 | Glynn | Decatur | Oklahoma |
| 19 | Hilton | Phoenix | Arizona |
| 20 | Barbette | New_Orleans | Louisiana |

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isin` function with list of values. Something like this:

```scala
val listIDs = Seq(6, 7, 8, 9, 13, 15, 16, 18)
val listStates = Seq("Illinois", "Oklahoma")
val listCityes = Seq("Orange", "Boca_Raton")

val conditionExpr = Seq(
  col("id").isin(listIDs: _*),
  !col("STATE").isin(listStates: _*),
  !col("CITY").isin(listCityes: _*)
).reduce(_ and _)

val df1 = df.filter(conditionExpr)

df1.show

//+---+------+------------+-------------+
//| id|  NAME|        CITY|        STATE|
//+---+------+------------+-------------+
//|  6|  Toby|   San_Diego|   California|
//| 13| Zelma|Newport_News|   California|
//| 16|Pattie|      Boston|Massachusetts|
//+---+------+------------+-------------+
```